# Parse XML Tag value for all files in directory using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I can't quite make the leap despite pre-existing similar questions. Help would be valued!

- I am trying to recursively parse all xml files in the directory/sub directory
- I am looking for the value that appears for the tag "Operator id"

Example source XML:

```
<Operators>
   <Operator id="OId_LD">
   <OperatorCode>LD</OperatorCode>
   <OperatorShortName>ARRIVA THE SHIRES LIMIT</OperatorShortName>
```

This is the code I have thus far:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
def jarv(target_folder):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(target_folder):
        for targetfile in files:
            if targetfile.endswith(".xml"):
                print targetfile
                dom=parse(targetfile)
                name = dom.getElementsByTagName('Operator_id')
                print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

This is the terminal command I am running:

```
python -c "execfile('xml_tag.py'); jarv('/Users/admin/Projects/AtoB_GTFS')"
```

And this is the error I receive:

tfl_64-31_-37434-y05.xml

```
encodings.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xml_tag.py", line 8, in jarv
    dom=parse(targetfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'encodings.xml'
(frigo)andytmac:AtoB_GTFS admin$ python -c "execfile('xml_tag.py'); jarv('/Users/admin/Projects/AtoB_GTFS')"
tfl_64-31_-37434-y05.xml
```

If I comment out the code after the 'print target file' line it does list all the xml files I have.

Thanks for your assistance,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at the right place (relative path) : when you use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target_folder):`, `files` is a list of the file names in the directory `root`, and not their absolute path.

Try remplacing `dom=parse(targetfile)` by `dom = parse(os.sep.join(root, targetfile))`